# Passing textbox value to ActionResult TempData in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am very new to MVC , and trying to learn from videos given for MVC. In one of the video i have gone through the use of Tempdata. In the video they have shown created action result with HTTPPOST and pass data from textbox to controller and then to view using Tempdata . I have tried to practice the same . But i am not getting value from textbox,always returning as null. Below is my code,

Controller as below,

```
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(string name)
        {
            TempData["uname"] =name;
            return RedirectToAction("GetUser");
        }

        public ActionResult GetUser()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

View for Create as below,

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create New User</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        <p>Enter your name : <input type="text" id="id" placeholder="Enter username"/></p>
        <p><input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Create"/></p>
    </div>
}
```

View for GetUser,

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetUser";
}

<h2>GetUser</h2>

<div>
    <h3>Welcome @TempData["uname"].ToString()</h3>
</div>
```

When i enter value in textbox and press button id parameter in Create action is null. Also i have not created any model class, as in video they have just shown as above code. Please give me some suggestions.

Regards
Sangeetha

Comment: You just missed the name attribute on your textbox. Just set the name attribute correctly that matches the name parameter on your controller action ex. name="name".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are not using any model to send the data across , you should provide your textbox with a name attribute and that name attribute must match on the controller action , change your create view text box as shown

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        <p>Enter your name : <input type="text" name="name" id="id" placeholder="Enter username"/></p>
        <p><input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Create"/></p>
    </div>
}
```

I have added the name attribute to the text box

Comment: Welcome , but in mvc it always advisable to use the models/viewmodels to the maximum extent ..

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing values from view to controller by using **input type=submit** then you must set **name** attribute to the input elements,then you need to mention that name in method **argument**.

```
<input type="text" name="txtname" id="txtname" placeholder="Enter username"/>
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Create"/>
```

**Note** : It will only work with input type="submit", it won't work with input type="button"

you don't need bind the **Tempdata** value with .ToString(). you can directly bind with **@TempData["uname"]**